# Store password hash in session. Good Idea?

Tags: php, apache, security, session

## Summarizing question

What arguments are there for or against saving password hashes in the session?

## Idea

Store the password hash (as it is in the DB) in the session upon login and validate it against the DB hash on each access in order automatically invalidate all sessions on password change.

## My thoughts

These are my thoughts so far on the subject.

### Pro

- Assuming two people legitimately share an account it would (mostly) prevent a sort of racecondition of both changing the password while the other is logged in. Confusion would only occur once and not twice.
- Assuming a malicious attack the legitimate user *could* kick out the attacker if detected early enough.

### Con

- Possible dataloss if person A submits a form right after person B changed the password.
- Assuming a malicious attack the attacker can kick out the legitimate user.

### Neutral

- No real performance impact. (Edit: Because I load the userinformation on each pageload anyway for other reasons.)
- Security issues are almost non existant. If someone has access to the server the effort of accessing the database which has *all* the hashes is comparable to the effort of accessing the session store, which has the hashes of the loggedin users.

## Answers and Comments please

I don't want to start a subjective discussion here. I would like to collect (as objective as possible) pros and cons on that subject. What have I not considered yet?

## Edit:

Clarification: The idea of invalidating all sessions (except the session used for changing the password) came from the thought of "If one person changes the password without telling certain other people there is a reason for that, thus they should immediately loose access.", assuming there are no malicious users (what a wonderfull world that would be...).

Comment: I would ask why should a session be invalidated because the password changed?

Comment: If you just want to invalidate the session upon password change, I would just use some sort of "last modification date" and use that. This would not be a proper way to prevent session hijacking, so if you want to prevent that, maybe google for another solution to prevent session hijacking. (last part is just an assumption)

Comment: @DarkFalcon It was an idea that occured to me. The idea was something along the lines of "If a person changes the password without the others knowing there is propably a reason for that, thus they should immediately lose access." I was not thinking about malicious users at that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The scenario about simultaneously changing the password sounds extremely rare and not a core premise to build a session architecture around. The scenario can also be better prevented with optimistic locking and other concurrency solutions.
2. You can invalidate sessions when a password is changed explicitly, you don't need to store the password in the session for that. This is trivial if you use a database to store sessions (preferably an in-memory database like Redis or memcached), but it's not impossible using standard PHP file-based sessions either. Just proactively nuke all active sessions by the given user when the password is changed, done.
3. The password is a secret and should stay out of circulation as much as possible. The hash is just a shadow of that secret, but even it you should keep secret. Storing it in the session is one step closer to accidentally leaking it than it would be when keeping it purely in the database.
4. There *is* a performance impact of doing a database lookup on every single page load.

Comment: About 4. I should have mentioned that I load the user on every pageload anyway for other reasons. About 1. haven't we all suffered from someone saying "it's extremely rare and should never happen" before? ;) About 2. and 3.: good points!

Comment: I'm not saying it's rare enough that you do not need to worry about it. I'm saying it's too rare to use as a primary tentpole for your session storage design.

Comment: Also, querying the database on each page load for user information is quite a performance drain. The typical architecture is that on login you store a copy of the relevant information in a *fast* data store. Files are okay, in-memory storage is better. When the data changes on the backend, you push that changed data to the stored copy, and/or invalidate that copy.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:**

Instead of storing your password hash at session, you can generate a "token", here you can generate a random sequence of characters and numbers, and store it at the session and give it a expiration time.

Let's suppose you and I share an account with password cow123. When I get logged in, i will receive token $124abc and you a token %xyz222, both tokens are related to password cow123.

Now you changed the password cow123 to cat321.

Nothing will happen to me because my token is still valid (You can create a table to persist valid tokens with expiration date column)

Comment: Right... havent thought about tokens at all. Thanks.